# Mostrar elementos de un array si se repiten y si coinciden con su posicion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este script actualmente me muestra los numeros repetidos entre 2 arrays pero no logro hacer para que me muestre los numeros repetidos y si su posicion coinciden

```js
var number_load = [2,3,4,1]
var number_input = [9,5,3,1]

for(var numbers in number_load){
    if(number_input.indexOf(number_load[numbers])>-1){
       console.log('Se repite el numero : ' + number_load[numbers])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estas planeando hacer este procedimiento en arreglos gigantescos y si los dos arreglos siempre serán del mismo tamaño, creo que puedes recorrer los arreglos manualmente.

```js
var number_load = [2,3,4,1];
var number_input = [9,5,3,1];

for(var i = 0; i < number_load.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < number_input.length; j++){
        if(number_load[i] == number_input[j])
            if(i == j)
                console.log('Se repite el numero : ' + number_load[i] + ' en la posición '+ (i + 1))
            else
                console.log('Se repite el numero : ' + number_load[i] + ' pero su posicion no coincide ')
    }
 }
```

Ten en cuenta que estamos comparando el primer arreglo contra el segundo y que la posición que se muestra en el mensaje es para usuarios finales (la verdadera posición mas uno).

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda !!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes la solucion debes comparar la posicion del elemento en los dos vectores con indexOf y ver si coinciden.

```js
var number_load = [2,3,4,1]
var number_input = [9,5,3,1]

for(var numbers in number_load){
    if(number_input.indexOf(number_load[numbers])>-1){
       console.log('Se repite el numero : ' + number_load[numbers])
       if(number_input.indexOf(number_load[numbers]) == 
       number_load.indexOf(number_load[numbers])){
       console.log("coincide lugar del numero " + number_load[numbers]);
    }
     
}

}
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda !!